# Image width and height not getting set while using XMLWorkerHelper in Itext

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext, xmlhelper

Hi i'm trying to add an image to my pdf. It's getting added but the problem is i'm not able to set user defined width and height. I'm using `XMLWorkerHelper` to convert the HTML code and write it in PDF.

```
try {
String image="<img alt=\"Not Loading\" src=\"C:\\Users\\sathesh_S\\Desktop\\Itext\\football.jpg\" style=\"width: 50px; height: 75px\" />";    
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Test.pdf"));
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
document.open();
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(image.getBytes());
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
document.close();
file.close();
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here i'm setting the width and height as 50 and 75 pixel. But the original image is getting added to the PDF. How can i rectify this.

Comment: Can you please post a complete working program? For example, your code snippet doesn't show how you are setting the width and height.

Comment: I'm setting the width and height in the string itself. You can see the String image.

Comment: Please post an entire program, rather than a code snippet.

Answer (score 4):

XMLWorker doesn't support width and height css properties on images[1].

The default image tag processor (ie `com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.Image`) uses width/height attributes of  tag. So there are two solutions:

1. write your own image tag processor (and probably CssAplier) for images (consult librabry source code for details), or simply:
2. use height and width attributes of img tag, for example:

   ```
   String image="<img src=\"football.jpg\" width=\"50px\" height=\"75px\"/>";
   ```

Second solution is much easier and should be enough in most cases.

[1] http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm